# What is the correct model for related tables with millions of rows?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, performance, query-performance

I need to create a question and answer tables that will have millions (maybe billions) of rows.

The current model is:

Question Table
id_question (PK, auto increment)
id_user
question_content
question_date

Answer Table
id_answer (PK, auto increment)
id_question
id_user
answer_content
answer_date

Is this a correct model (considering better query performance)? Should I add the id_question and id_user columns to the primary key?

Thanks

Comment: "better query performance" for what queries?

Comment: It will work like StackExchange, queries as simple as "SELECT * FROM Question WHERE id_question = @id" and "SELECT * FROM Answer WHERE id_question = @question ORDER BY answer_date DESC". But my question is regarding better performance considering indexes and correct modeling. Things like should I add an auto increment column for this answers table and let it be the only primary key? Or should I add it as an unique identifier (or something like), making a composite primary key with id_question, id_answer and id_user? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. Your tables would look something like this then ( oracle ddl ) :

```
create table Users (id int,
                    name varchar2(1000),
                    constraint pk_users primary key (id)
);

create table Questions (id int,
                        user_id int,
                        content CLOB,
                        question_date date,
                        constraint pk_questions primary key (id),
                        constraint fk_questions_user_id foreign key (user_id) references users(id)
                        );

create table Answers (id int,
                      question_id int,
                      user_id int,
                      content CLOB,
                      answer_date date,
                      constraint pk_answers primary key (id),
                      constraint fk_answers_questions foreign key (question_id) references Questions(id), 
                      constraint fk_answers_user_id foreign key (user_id) references users(id)
);
```

Comment: The user_id is required on both tables because who answers the question is not the same person who posts the question.

Comment: ahh, ok.

Then your original model is fine. I'll modify my answer as well